# Call $mdDialog ( Angular Material ) Confirmation instead of Default Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, material-design, angular-material

script

```
if (true) {
    if(!confirm("Are you sure ?")) 
    {
     event.preventDefault();
     }
  }
```

How can i call Angular Material dialogue box instead of default javascript confirmation ? Something like

```
function(event) {
      var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Are you sure ?')
            .targetEvent(event)
            .ok('ok')
            .cancel('cancel');

        $mdDialog.show(!confirm).then(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    };
```

Comment: non-`confirm()` dialogs are almost always async, needing a callback instead of a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this pen. Just pass `$event` in `ng-click` and use `$mdDialog` service provided by material library to open a alert dialoge box. 
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/KzvwXq

HTMLfile

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showConfirm($event)">
  Confirm Dialog
</md-button>
```

JS file

```
$scope.showConfirm = function(ev) {
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Are you sure?')
      .textContent('Are you really sure?')
      .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Yes')
      .cancel('No');

$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
  $scope.status = 'Yes';
}, function() {
  $scope.status = 'No';
});
```

Comment: thanks but it's not for button click. Instead i am using it for form $dirty check

Comment: You can  watch your form collection for any changes in `$dirty` and call the function to open the dialoge. Check that pen again. I made some changes.

Comment: Updated your answer, which does show the alert as expected. However it is not preventing `event.preventDefault();` until user acknowledges it. thanks